# Why is there nothing in my conntrack's output?

Tags: linux, networking, iptables, connection, linux-kernel

I have a simple bench:
Linux machine with `nf_conntrack` module loaded. This machine is between two other hosts (A and B), so it routes traffic between two networks. When I send ping from A to B through my Linux "router" there is nothing (`0 flow entries have been shown`) in `conntrack -L` output.
What should I do to make conntrack work?

UPD: It is debian 9 with Linux kernels 4.4, 4.9 (both have the same behavior).

Comment: What's a silent downvote? Please point out what's wrong.

Comment: (not me but I can guess): not enough informations? even the kernel version could affect results here.

Comment: @A.B updated the question.

Comment: When you say `nf_conntrack` is loaded. Anything else related to conntrack also loaded?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the Linux *conntrack* module changes over kernel versions.

In kernel 4.9 on Debian 9 at least, the `nf_conntrack` module is a core module for netfilter's conntrack facility:

```
$ /sbin/modinfo /tmp/lin/lib/modules/4.9.0-12-amd64/kernel/net/netfilter/nf_conntrack.ko 
filename:       /tmp/lin/lib/modules/4.9.0-12-amd64/kernel/net/netfilter/nf_conntrack.ko
license:        GPL
depends:        
retpoline:      Y
intree:         Y
vermagic:       4.9.0-12-amd64 SMP mod_unload modversions 
parm:           tstamp:Enable connection tracking flow timestamping. (bool)
parm:           acct:Enable connection tracking flow accounting. (bool)
parm:           nf_conntrack_helper:Enable automatic conntrack helper assignment (default 0) (bool)
parm:           expect_hashsize:uint
```

There's no IPv4 involved here. So ICMP, part of IPv4 will not trigger anything. For this you have to load the additional module `nf_conntrack_ipv4`.

```
$ /sbin/modinfo /tmp/lin/lib/modules/4.9.0-12-amd64/kernel/net/ipv4/netfilter/nf_conntrack_ipv4.ko 
filename:       /tmp/lin/lib/modules/4.9.0-12-amd64/kernel/net/ipv4/netfilter/nf_conntrack_ipv4.ko
license:        GPL
alias:          ip_conntrack
alias:          nf_conntrack-2
depends:        nf_conntrack,nf_defrag_ipv4
retpoline:      Y
intree:         Y
vermagic:       4.9.0-12-amd64 SMP mod_unload modversions
```

On more recent kernels, for example 4.19.0-0.bpo.6-amd64 from stretch-backports, the IPv4 and IPv6 modules were consolidated because it was found to be overally cheaper. You have instead:

```
$ /sbin/modinfo /tmp/lin/lib/modules/4.19.0-0.bpo.6-amd64/kernel/net/netfilter/nf_conntrack.ko 
filename:       /tmp/lin/lib/modules/4.19.0-0.bpo.6-amd64/kernel/net/netfilter/nf_conntrack.ko
license:        GPL
alias:          nf_conntrack-10
alias:          nf_conntrack-2
alias:          ip_conntrack
depends:        nf_defrag_ipv6,libcrc32c,nf_defrag_ipv4
retpoline:      Y
intree:         Y
name:           nf_conntrack
vermagic:       4.19.0-0.bpo.6-amd64 SMP mod_unload modversions 
signat:         PKCS#7
signer:         
sig_key:        
sig_hashalgo:   md4
parm:           tstamp:Enable connection tracking flow timestamping. (bool)
parm:           acct:Enable connection tracking flow accounting. (bool)
parm:           nf_conntrack_helper:Enable automatic conntrack helper assignment (default 0) (bool)
parm:           expect_hashsize:uint
```

So if you followed a recent documentation, it would not have stated to also explicitely load the module `nf_conntrack_ipv4` in addition to `nf_conntrack`: there's no such module anymore.

Solution for your kernel version:

```
modprobe nf_conntrack_ipv4
```

About dependencies:

- running `conntrack -E` alone will already load `nf_conntrack` as dependency. Not `nf_conntrack_ipv4`!
- any stateful firewalling rule with *iptables* or *nft* with ip or inet families will automatically pull `nf_conntrack_ipv4`
- on the host (the initial network namespace), simply loading the module (so `nf_conntrack` on recent kernels, but `conntrack -E` would do it by itself, or `nf_conntrack_ipv4` on older kernels) is enough to have `conntrack -E` operational.
- on a (non-initial) network namespace, conntrack (and various netfilter related functionalities) is deactivated until it has a dependency. This avoids that having one module loaded for the host (or for a given network namspace) suddenly activates its features on every other namespaces. Once activated there's probably no way to deactivate it again without destroying the network namespace.
- there are exceptions to the point above. Including the infamous [`br_netfilter`](http://ebtables.netfilter.org/documentation/bridge-nf.html) which until recently was working globally on all network namespaces as soon as loaded (even indirectly by a non-initial namespace, when using the [`-m physdev`](https://manpages.debian.org/iptables/iptables-extensions.8#physdev) iptables match)

Answer (score 0):

Conntrack only becomes active if your iptables or nftables ruleset has at least one conntrack-based rule (e.g. nftables `ct` or iptables `-m state`, or a NAT/masquerade rule, or *possibly* `-j REJECT`), otherwise its conntrack_ops are unregistered – most likely to avoid the extra resource usage.

For example (if your rules currently don't use conntrack yet), add the following at the top of your 'input' or 'forward' chain:

```
ct state {established, related} accept
```

```
-A INPUT -m state --state established,related -j ACCEPT
```

Comment: I don't think so. I deployed new clean VM. `ip_tables` module was auto-loaded with just ACCEPT policy (there is no conntrack usage). But `conntrack -L` started to show connections (in case of `nf_conntrack` and `nf_conntrack_ipv4` modules loaded)